# Maya's nameCommand not able to call functions

Tags: python, maya

I'm having an issue with calling functions from nameCommand's in Maya used with hotkeys. I can't tell if it's a Maya or Python issue.

The following MEL works as expected

```
proc myTest() {
    print("test");
}

nameCommand -ann "test" -command "myTest()" testCommand;
hotkey -k "l" -name "testCommand";
```

However, translated to Python, I get an error

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def myPythonTest():
    print("myPythonTest")

cmds.nameCommand("pythonTestCommand", ann="pythonTest", command="myPythonTest()", sourceType="python")
cmds.hotkey(k="l", name="pythonTestCommand")

// Error: line 1: Cannot find procedure "myPythonTest".
```

Is it the wrong way to call functions in Python, or is something else going on? I've noticed that the parentheses are being stripped, and calling the function with `myPythonTest()` from the script editor works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmds.nameCommand("pythonTestCommand", ann="pythonTest", command='python("myPythonTest()")', sourceType="python")
cmds.hotkey(k="l", name="pythonTestCommand")
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was needed. Out of curiosity and understanding: Why does it work? What does python("") do?

Comment: I don't think sourceType is actually working, so using python mel command to call the python function more here http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/python.html

Comment: I see. I tried googling for the python function, and also looked in the documentation for it, however in the python commands instead of mel. But great, makes somewhat sense, and thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer I believe [Achayan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928246/mayas-namecommand-not-able-to-call-functions#comment55648238_33928760) is correct in the assesment
that sourceType seems to be broken.

If you want to be able to pass python code to a `nameCommand` you need to
first create a `runTimeCommand`

```py
def testy():
    print('hello')

# There is no way to edit a runtime command so we need to check if it
# exists and then remove it if it does.
my_command_name = 'my_runtime_command'
if cmds.runTimeCommand(my_command_name, q=True, exists=True):
    cmds.runTimeCommand(my_command_name, e=True, delete=True)

cmds.runTimeCommand(
    my_command_name, 
    ann='My Command', 
    category='User', 
    command='testy()', 
    commandLanguage='python'
    )
cmds.nameCommand('my_name_command', ann='My Command', command=my_command_name)
cmds.hotkey(k='1', name='my_name_command')
```

As you see you don't need to provide a sourceType, the `nameCommand` is just
a string representation of the runtimecommand and will just execute the
given `runTimeCommand`. So the real place to specify execution language is in the `commandLanguage` flag of the `runTimeCommand`.